# Elm byte decoding within Http.get

Tags: byte, elm, decoding

I'm pretty new to elm and stuck with a problem regarding populating my model with data from my backend. I'm curently able to make a get request to the server which returns a byte[] (the data is any kind of image,audio or video), which works fine when just displaying this data by for example Html.img. When I try to use Http.get (src: https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http) to populate my model it requires a decoder. The problem is, that Bytes.Decode.bytes requires an Int to know how many bytes have to be decoded.
So my question is: Is there any way to access the byte width while still matching the type pattern of Http.get?

Here's a simple example of my problem:

```
import Bytes exposing (Bytes)
import Bytes.Decode exposing (Decoder, bytes, decode)
import GeneralTypes exposing (Msg(..))
import Http

getMediaFromUrl : Cmd Msg
getMediaFromUrl = Http.get
        { url = "http://localhost:8090/image/2006/aa@a.de/session"
        , expect = Http.expectBytes GetThumbnail decodeBytes
        }

decodeBytes: Bytes.Bytes -> Decoder Bytes
decodeBytes bytesToDecode= let
                fileSize =
                    bytesToDecode |> Bytes.width
              in
              Bytes.Decode.bytes fileSize
```

```
module GeneralTypes exposing (..)

import Bytes exposing (Bytes)
import Http

type Msg = GetThumbnail (Result Http.Error Bytes)
```

Comment: Does the example in the docs for getting byte string width (https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/bytes/latest/Bytes-Decode#strings) help in your scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `expectBytes` function requires you to specify a Bytes decoder, which is useful if you immediately want to translate the bytes into something more meaningful in your code.

If, however, you want to retain the raw `Bytes` in your application without having to clone or otherwise read the bytes at this time, you may find [`expectBytesResponse`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#expectBytesResponse) more useful. It has the signature:

```
expectBytesResponse : (Result x a -> msg) -> (Response Bytes -> Result x a) -> Expect msg
```

This does not take a decoder as input. It takes two functions which let you translate `Response Bytes` to a `Result` and another function (the first argument) which lets you translate that `Result` into a `Msg`. Through each of those steps you can retain the original `Bytes` reference, to do with as you please at a later time.

You will, however, have to manually handle more HTTP response scenarios, but at least you gain full control over what to do with your Bytes.